# SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait does not wait?

Tags: java, multithreading, macos, swing

Following code worked fine

```
abstract class FunctionRunnable<V> implements Runnable {
  protected abstract V calculate();
  private V result;
  private Throwable thr;

  public synchronized final void run() {
    try {
      result = calculate();
    }
    catch (Throwable thr) {
      this.thr = thr;
    }
  }

  public synchronized final V getResult() {
    if (thr != null) {
      throw new RuntimeException(thr);
    }
    return result;
  }
}

...
final FunctionRunnable<Boolean> runnable = new FunctionRunnable<Boolean>() {
  public Boolean calculate() {
    return doCalculation();
  }

  private boolean doCalculation() {
    ...
  }
});
SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(runnable);
final Boolean resultObj = runnable.getResult();
final boolean result = resultObj.booleanValue();
```

until Apple released 1.6.0_31 for which users of our application *sometimes* are getting an NPE in the last line.

Do you see a bug in the code or do other people have found similar problems with this particular Java update?

Comment: Are you calling invokeAndWait() from the EDT, or from another thread?

Comment: @JBNizet NPE is not the expected result either way.

Comment: The javadoc just says: "It should'nt be called from the EventDispatchThread.". But it doesn't say what happens if called from the EDT. So the result might be undetermined.

Comment: It is called from a non-EDT-thread.

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. It looks like a bug if you really get this exception with the above code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look in to the implementation of EventQueue.invokeAndWait you will see that it does not correctly handle spurious wakeup. It calls lock.wait() then does not check whether the runnable has actually finished executing - this means invokeAndWait can return before your runnable has finished executing!

For some reason, spurious wakeup has started happening with reasonable frequency in update 31 on mac os, exposing this long standing bug in EventQueue. I'm not sure what has changed, it doesn't happen in any other versions of Java.

We fixed this by implementing our own invokeAndWait method with a simple boolean check for completion of the runnable.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm now trying to simulate `invokeAndWait` using `invokeLater` and a wrapping runnable.

Answer (score 3):

My SSCCE:

```
public abstract class FunctionRunnable<V> implements Runnable {
  private V result;
  private Throwable thr;

  protected abstract V calculate();

  public synchronized final void run() {
    try { result = calculate(); } catch (Throwable thr) { this.thr = thr; }
  }

  public synchronized final V getResult() {
    if (thr != null) throw new RuntimeException(thr);
    return result;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final FunctionRunnable<Boolean> runnable = new FunctionRunnable<Boolean>() {
      public Boolean calculate() { return doCalculation(); }
      private boolean doCalculation() {
        try { Thread.sleep(2000); } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        return false;
      }};
    SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(runnable);
    System.out.println(runnable.getResult().booleanValue());
  }
}
```

My Java version:

```
$java -version
java version "1.6.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_31-b04-415-11M3635)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.6-b01-415, mixed mode)
```

Started, ran for 2 seconds, printed `false`.

Comment: For me it also always returns false, even when looping 100,000 times. But we are getting similar exceptions since a few weeks, only from OS X users which are using 1.6.0_31.

Comment: So what you are saying is that you were unable to throw together an SSCCE that provokes the problem? Then you don't really know whether the problem is within this code or with something totally unrelated.

Comment: The problem is not reliable reproducible: I've changed the question accordingly.

Comment: Yes, but you say you've **never** reproduced it using the posted code? That's the issue that I'm worried about.

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes get NullPonterExeption.... weird

java version "1.6.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_31-b04-415-11M3635)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.6-b01-415, mixed mode)